# How to no-index specific pages on shopify? Don't want to use "contains" example for shopify, can I just type "="? And what denotes as the handle?

Tags: shopify, liquid, noindex, liquid-template

Shopify says to utilize the following sample to noindex a specific page in shopify.

To exclude a specific page, paste the following code in the section:

```
{% if handle contains 'page-handle-you-want-to-exclude' %}
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
{% endif %}
```

However, the "contains" is an issue I think. For example, I specifically want to noindex the default created /collections and /collections/all pages. But, if I noindex those with a contains option, any page handle that "contains" that would be no-index. That is an issue because then all collections would be noindex by doing that to '/collections' and if I just do it to 'collections/all', that would also noindex a collection that utilizes the url /collections/all-supplements.

Instead of contains, can I do =? Or what should I place to force an exact url to be noindex?

After determining what the proper operator is... what does Shopify consider to be the handle?

Would I do 'collections' or '/collections'  or '/collections/'?
For the other, would I do 'collections/all' or '/collections/all' or '/collections/all/'?

Answer (score 0):

For the "/collections" page, you may use the [request](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/request) object like this:

```
{% if request.page_type == 'list-collections' %}
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
{% endif %}
```

For the collection page automatically created, the handle will always be "all" (/collections/all), and you may use a strict condition:

```
{% if handle == 'all' %}
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
{% endif %}
```